# Implement a tuned svm model to the train and test situation

Tags: r, svm

I did a classification with an `svm`model through the `e1071` package. The data looks like this:

```
 dtm[140:145] %>% str()
 Observations: 387
'data.frame':   387 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ comes: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ able : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hours: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ type : Factor w/ 4 levels "-1","0","1","9": 3 3 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 ...
```

The goal is to predict `type` through all other data in `dtm`. The problem was that the results were really bad (Accuracy ~ 0.6). This was among other things due to the imbalanced sample I got:

```
prop.table(table(dtm$type))
         -1           0           1           9 
0.025839793 0.005167959 0.180878553 0.788113695
```

So, I tried to `tune` the model based on [this approach](http://rischanlab.github.io/SVM.html).

Without any tuning, the results look like this:

```
x <- subset(dtm, select=-type)
y <- dtm$type

classifier <- svm(type~.,data = dtm)
pred<- predict(classifier,x)
confusionMatrix(pred, y)

           Reference
Prediction  -1   0   1   9
        -1   0   0   0   0
        0    0   2   0   0
        1    1   0  54   1
        9    9   0  16 304
```

With the tuning, the result looks like this (I also implemented `class.weights` based on `prop.table(table(dtm$type)`,`smv_tune` said best `gamma` would be 0.5 and best`cost` would be 1).

```
svm_tune <- tune(svm, train.x=x, train.y=y, 
class.weights = c("-1" = 9.439025, 
                   "0" = 22.76471, 
                   "1" = 2.866667, 
                   "9" = 1.994845), 
                   ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:2), 
                   gamma=c(.5,1,2)))

svm_model_after_tune <- svm(type ~ ., data=dtm, cost=1, gamma=0.5, 
                            class.weights = c("-1" = 9.439025, 
                                               "0" = 22.76471,
                                               "1" = 2.866667, 
                                               "9" = 1.994845))

pred_tuned <- predict(svm_model_after_tune,x)
confusionMatrix(pred_tuned,y)


          Reference
Prediction  -1   0   1   9
        -1  10   0   0   0
        0    0   2   0   0
        1    0   0  70   0
        9    0   0   0 305
```

As you can see, the `svm_model_after_tune` works well. But when I try to implement the model in a train-test situation. The results are not much better than before. Actually, they are even worse:

```
train_index <- createDataPartition(dtm$type, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
train <- dtm[train_index,]
test <- dtm[-train_index,]

classifier <- svm(type~., 
                  data = train,
                  kernel = "radial", 
                  cross = 10, 
                  cost = 1,
                  gamma = 0.5,
                  class.weights = c("-1" = 9.439025, 
                                    "0" = 22.76471, 
                                    "1" = 2.866667, 
                                    "9" = 1.994845))   

pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=test)
confusionMatrix(pred, test$type)


          Reference
Prediction -1  0  1  9
        -1  0  0  0  0
        0   0  0  0  0
        1   0  0  0  0
        9  10  4 33 48
```

The question is how can I implement the `tune` model in such a way that I can benefit from?